# How to execute script inside function that is triggered

Tags: php, wordpress, function

```
function when_a_review_gets_submitted ($review, $post_id) {
// Do something
}

add_action('rwp_after_saving_review', 'when_a_review_gets_submitted', 11, 2);
```

I have this WP_Query and loop to update a custom field of every childpage of the parentpage were somebody has left a review.

```
// Set up the objects needed
$hosting_provider_query = new WP_Query();
global $post;
$hosting_pagina_titel = $post->post_title;  
$search_all_pages = $hosting_provider_query->query(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    //Only get pages where custom field 'name_hosting_provider' equals Page title
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'naam_hosting_provivder',
            'value' => $hosting_pagina_titel,
            'compare'   => '='
        ),

    ),
));

// Loop through all pages and find Page's children
$loop_through_all_child_pages = get_page_children( get_the_ID(), $search_all_pages );

// Loop through everything we got back
if(!empty($loop_through_all_child_pages)){
    foreach($loop_through_all_child_pages as $child_page){
        // get the ID of each childpage
        $get_child_page_ID = $child_page->ID;
        // get the ID of each parent page of the child pages
        $get_parent_page_ID = get_queried_object_id();
        // Get the average score from post_meta of the parent page
        $get_average_score = get_post_meta( $get_parent_page_ID, 'rwp_user_score', true );
        // update each custom field of the childs with the average score data from the post meta of parent page
        update_field('gemiddelde_score_hosting_provider', $get_average_score, $get_child_page_ID);
    }
}
```

How can I correctly execute this code within the above function?

**EDIT**

Ok I figured this out, the function is working properly when I remove the parameters $review and $post_id. And when I remove the add action:

```
add_action('rwp_after_saving_review', 'when_a_review_gets_submitted', 11, 2);
```

and replace it with:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'when_a_review_gets_submitted' );
```

but I think this is a bit overkill for what I am trying to achieve. If I understand template_redirect it executes the function everytime a page is visited with that template? Am I correct?

So when I have 900 child pages it updates every custom field "gemiddelde_score_hosting_provider" when a page with that template is visited? So 900 times every single time a page with that template is visited? Am I correct in this one?

Is there a way to only update the custom field of the childs from the parent page where the review is submitted?

Comment: have you tried pasting the bigger code inside the function?

Comment: Yes, nothing gets updated... and I dont know how to do it inside this function

Comment: ok well if you paste your code inside the function you need to replace `$hosting_pagina_titel = $post->post_title;` with `$hosting_pagina_titel = get_the_title($post_id);` and it should work

Comment: @Ovidash this is not working. I get another error: Notice: Undefined variable: post_id

Comment: Your function is `function when_a_review_gets_submitted ($review, $post_id) {` which means it takes as parameters `$review` and `$post_id` so maybe $post_id isn't coming from the hook `rwp_after_saving_review` ?? Is that hook custom made or something from a plugin?

Comment: @Ovidash this is the original function comming from the documentation from the plugin:

function rex_my_action ($review, $post_id) {
    // Build your action after the review is saved.
}
add_action('rwp_after_saving_review', 'rex_my_action', 11, 2);

https://help.micheleivani.com/article/46-wordpress-custom-hooks

as you can see it has $post_id in it

Comment: I edited my question, is there a way to only update the fields of the hosting provider packages where a review is submitted somehow?

Comment: ok, the original hook was the best one and you already have the $post_id; what are you doing with doing a wp_query when you already have the post id? Why do you use get_the_ID(); when you have the post id? Please update your code to use the provided $post_id given by the function and not the ones you get out of thin air.